# How does calling "setState" as a callback in a function, without any new state value, successfully update the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I saw this code snippet recently, and am wondering how the state variable actually gets updated here. This is the authentication state observer used in firebase authentication to determine if a user is signed in ([docs reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data)).
Normally, this is how it functions:

```js
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null)
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    setUserData(user); // can now access properties of user
  }
});
```

However, this code updates `userData` in the exact same way by placing `setUserData` in place of the callback in the function:

```js
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null)
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUserData);
```

Both of these functions set `userData` as the same object. How does this work, in the second snippet, where the state is updated by not using a tangible value to update the state?

Comment: In your second example the function `setUserData` is given as a callback to `onAuthStateChanged`. It is `onAuthStateChanged` that calls the callback, in this case it calls `setUserData` instead of a user supplied function.

Comment: What you really care is the truthy value of `userData`, so even if user is `false`, `undefined`, `null`, it doesn't matter and it makes the `if (user)` unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second call uses a function that is defined elsewhere as the callback, while the first uses a newly defined function.

See example below:

```js
function log(data) {
  console.log(data);
}

function someFunction(callback) {
  setTimeout(()=>{ callback("my data")}, 1000);
}


someFunction( (data)=> console.log(data) ); // use new function
someFunction( log ); // reuse a defined function
```

Answer (score 3):

That's simply the way it works in javascript. Functions are a first class citizens which you can assign to variables and pass as an arguments. Here, `setUserData` is passed as a first argument of `onAuthStateChanged`. For a better understanding, consider something like this:

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null)

const handleAuth = user => {
  if (user) {
    setUserData(user);
  }
}

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(handleAuth);
```

Both `setUserData` and `handleAuth` expects `user` as a first argument, so both functions are ok to pass as a [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) to `onAuthStateChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following way is same:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => setUserData(user))
// OR,
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(setUserData)
```

So, when you use arrow function you explicitly set user as parameter to setUserData and when you use it as callback it implicitly sets user parameter to it.

Comment: Nitpicking: They achieve the same ting, but they are not the same. The first one define a function, and therefore takes a little bit longer time (unless the compiler is advanced enough that it can inline it)

Comment: Also, the first one keeps the context (`this` will remain the same).